# Adding an extra step to a step by step process

Tags: jquery

I've created a step by step process that will eventually form a test. It grabs rows of data from Wordpress, with each row being a question.

I want to add an extra step at the end which will act as a review your answers page. On the current last step it shows a submit button.

**How can I change the current last step to show a next button that hides the last .form-row div and shows another div with a submit button on it?**

Maybe it's because I've been staring at it for so long but can someone help me with this please?

This is my code so far:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
jQuery(function($) {
$(document).ready(function() {    

    // prepend a 'previous' button to all form-rows except the first
    $('<button>').addClass('previous').appendTo($('.inner').not(':first'));

    // hide all form-rows, but not the first one
    $('.form-row').not(':first').hide();

    // hide on last step
    $('button.next').last().hide();

    // add the submit button to the last form-row
    $('<input>').addClass('submit').prop('type', 'submit').val('Submit').appendTo($('.form-row:last'));

    // handle the previous button, we need to use 'on' here as the
    // previous buttons don't exist in the dom at page load
    $('.form-row').on('click', 'button.previous', function(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().prev('div.form-row').show();
    });

    $('button.next').click(function(e) {
        // prevent the next buttons from submitting the form
        e.preventDefault();
        // hide this form-row, and show the next one
        $(this).parents('div.form-row').hide().next('div.form-row').show();
    });    

});
});
</script>
```

HTML:

```
                <?php $counter = 1; if(get_field('step_by_step_test')): ?>
                <?php while(the_repeater_field('step_by_step_test')): ?>        
                <div class="form-row">
                    <h2 style="float:left;margin-left:7px;"><?php the_title(); ?></h2>
                    <h2 style="float:right;"><?php echo $counter; ?> of <?php echo $total; ?></h2>
                    <div class="clear"></div>
                    <div id="module-area" style="margin-top:0px!IMPORTANT;">
                        <div id="modules-top"></div>
                        <div id="modules-repeat">                           
                            <?php if(get_sub_field('test_image')): ?>
                            <?php while(has_sub_field('test_image')): ?> 
                                <img class="training" src="<?php echo the_sub_field('image'); ?>" />
                            <?php endwhile; ?> 
                            <?php endif; ?>         

                            <br /><br />    
                            <p class="training"><b><?php echo the_sub_field('question'); ?></b></p>

                            <?php if(get_sub_field('answer_options')): ?>
                            <?php while(has_sub_field('answer_options')): ?> 
                                <p class="contact-form"> 
                                    <input style="width: 20px;" type="checkbox" name="CheckboxGroup<?php echo $counter; ?>[]" value="<?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>" />
                                    <?php echo the_sub_field('answer'); ?>
                                </p>                
                            <?php endwhile; ?> 
                            <?php endif; ?>
                            <div class="inner"></div>
                            <button class="next"></button>
                            <div class="clear"></div>
                        </div>
                        <div style="margin-bottom:5px;" id="modules-bottom"></div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <?php $counter++; endwhile; ?> 
                <?php endif; ?>
```

Comment: You will also need to include the related `html` code. Even better if you can setup a quick http://jsfiddle.net workbench!

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/aEz2J/ - This fiddle is not the fix. It is simply to be used as a workbench.

Comment: @bPratik Ok. The div form-row is within a while loop so I'd need to put a hidden div within that and show it on the last step... whilst hiding the final questions and answers.

Comment: From your last comment I thought you fixed it! What is it that you are still having trouble with?

Comment: See the updated fiddle - http://jsfiddle.net/pratik136/aEz2J/

Comment: what I have done is add comments to make it clear where the loop begins/ends, and thus where you need to put in the last `div`. Also, I made a change to the script that hides the previous button on the last div, but if you want that to appear, you simply need to remove the `.not(':last')` bit from the js code. Let me know if this helps.

Comment: @bPratik Thanks. As it's all within a loop I don't have as much control as just pasting several of the steps and then just putting a different step at the end. I need to hide it within the one loop and show it on the last step.

Answer (score 0):

I'm counting kids, then showing the questions (sans next/prev) buttons. Result is what I believe you're attempting. http://jsfiddle.net/TWB6Z/

JS

```
$(document).ready(function() {

var EZcounter = $('.form-row').length - 1;

    {...your code...}

    $('.form-row:nth-child(' + EZcounter + 'n) .next').click(function() {
        $('.form-row').show();
        $('.previous, .next').hide();
    });
});​
```